# How to click a button and play a sound in action script

Tags: flash, actionscript

I want to add a second function to a button to hit the button and have a song play and loop. until you hit a button to stop it. Every thing i keep finding does not seem to want do work they way.

Comment: At first try. Then ask question. What is your specific problem?

Comment: I want to be able to play a song from my library with coding when i hit a button. Well I would like it to stop one song and start a different song, but i can not get the coding to play the song at all. I just need a song to start when i hit the button, but I need the coding to do it.

Comment: I have a large project with lots buttons and different areas. I am adding background music. If i can just add the sound changes to buttons with a bit of code it would make everything easier.

Answer (score 1):

Use sound.play().
It returns a soundchannel on which you can then use stop().
Here are the AS3 reference links. Try it and comment if you have an issue.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Sound.html

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/SoundChannel.html